# How to use a newer version of iisadministration powershell module?

Tags: powershell

I see in powershell gallery that there is a newer version of the iisadministration module than the one that shipped with Server 2016.

I got it installed using:

```
install-module -name IISadministration -scope currentuser -verbose -force -SkipPublisherCheck
```

I now have two versions, the newer one installed for the currentuser and the original that shipped with the OS.

`Import-Module IISAdministration` was successful and so was explicitly specifying the psd1 path.  However, when I try to use `New-IISSiteBinding` (included in the newer version), it complains that the cmdlet is not recognized.

Article referencing the new cmdlt
https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/introducing-iisadministration-in-the-powershell-gallery

Can anyone please help?  Thanks

Comment: Seems to be **SuperUser** question

Comment: Have you tried Import-Module -Version ?

Comment: That worked, thank you!